# Is there any evidence that Rey was imagining Luke's island?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, as Kylo Ren interrogates Rey, he tells her,

> You've been so lonely.  At night, desperate to sleep, you'd imagine an ocean.  I can see it...I can see the island.

At the end of the film, Rey finds Luke Skywalker on a small rocky island in the middle of a large body of water.

The novelization says that the planet was

> mostly ocean, dotted with a sprinkling of towering islands...

**Is there any evidence that the island imagined by Rey is Luke's?**

Comment: really interesting question, +1. Also, I was sure this was already asked somewhere but I can't find the dupe. Oh well. :)

Comment: @RedCaio : Thanks!  I follow the-force-awakens tag pretty closely and haven't seen it asked...

Comment: i assumed it was, that luke was calling out to force users, or that she had subconsciously found him. but i have no proof, and wonder if well get any till the next movie

Comment: I think someone just mentioned it in an answer/question but it wasn't the subject of the actual question, so not really a dupe. Maybe I'm just going crazy.

Comment: In the film, didn't images of the ocean and island flash onscreen during the interrogation scene? I seem to remember that the images did resemble the actual island at the end of the film.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Hmmm...I've seen it twice and don't recall seeing that either time.  (But still, it could have happened.)

Comment: I don't remember seeing and ocean and island scene during the interagation either, and I saw it twice. I remember a flashback to when she was _left behind_ on jakku

Comment: When Rey touched the lightsaber, I'm pretty sure JJ intended for that to be a Force vision, which she has had while "dreaming" before. This one was just for the audience's benefit. Of course, I don't have any explicit evidence... just my best guess.

Comment: NO. Nothing in novelizations or the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes, Rey confirms this in *The Last Jedi*.

When Rey enters the tree on the island containing the sacred Jedi texts, she and Luke have the following exchange:

> **LUKE:** You've seen this place.
>
> **REY:** Only in dreams.

Thus, Rey confirms that she had imagined the island, or at least this specific location on it, before ever having set foot there.

Given her strong Force connection to the place (for instance, she hears whispers that draw her to the tree shortly after her arrival), it seems improbable that she had been imagining some island other than this one.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure there is direct evidence (I haven't read the novelization). However, based on the force visions Rey was getting during the movie in rapid succession and often, I had always surmised her dreaming of an ocean and an island, was the force trying to show her where Luke was all along.

> Obviously she would have no idea what it meant or where it actually was, but Maz mentions that Rey's future is tied to Luke, and it is Luke's lightsaber that gives her a wave of visions.

I don't think its much of a stretch to see the force vision connection to Luke's actual location.

Comment: In the vision given by the lightsaber, it also sounds like (at least to me) the voice says "Climb the stairs." When she reaches the island, she has to climb a long set of stairs before finding Luke.

Comment: also note that, as far as we know, Rey has never *seen* an ocean, yet she knows what one looks like enough for Ren to pick it out...

Comment: "a **wave** of visions" I see what you did there!

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Whoa, I can't believe I didn't realize that. After all, if she has seen an ocean in reality, it should be as distant and misty a memory as the one of being abandoned with Plutt on Jakku.

Comment: @Mayshar The close captioning for that scene in the move never mentions climbing stairs. Also the island where Luke was finally found was never in the vision. The only times Luke was present was when he witnessing the burning of the temple and there was no such temple on the island; it also would not have made much sense to hide on the island where Kylo burned the temple given the First Order searching for his location. It is very likely she was having other dreams that had shown her the location, but it was nothing related to the lightsaber visions. This answer should be edited/updated.